# multiple IF statement issue

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to make double conditions on google sheet to make the cell not to show the error of empty output.

```
=IFS( K8="", "",K8="COMMANDE LIVRER", "",QUERY('A PAYER'!G9:K,"Select J,K WHERE G='A8'",1))
```

first condition is to check if the cell K8 is empty to return empty, and second one is to check if K8 not equal to "COMMANDE LIVRER".
thank you

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IF((K8="")+(K8="COMMANDE LIVRER"),,
 QUERY('A PAYER'!G9:K, "select J,K where G='A8'", 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute query if K8 IS NOT NULL AND IS NOT "COMMANDE LIVRER".

`=if(K8="","",if(K8="COMMANDE LIVRER", "",QUERY('A PAYER'!G9:K,"Select J,K WHERE G='A8'",1)))`